# UITextField causes crash in iOS 5, works fine in iOS 4

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

I have a really weird problem where if I click on a UITextField, any UITextField in my app will crash with this error:

> 0_CreateCachePathEmbedded(__CFString const*, unsigned char)
>
> 0x0246ac4f  <+0375>  mov    (%esi),%esi
>
> Thread 5 WebThread: Program received signal: "EXC_BAD_ACCESS"

[image]

I tried adding a UITextField in interface builder not linked to anything, still get the same crash. Everything works fine in iOS4.3 simulator.

What on earth could be going on??

Comment: Sorry, I didn't realise it would shrink it so much.. I'm not sure how to get the full crash dump from xcode but it says: 
0_CreateCachePathEmbedded(__CFString const*, unsigned char) on the left
and on the right it says "Thread 5 WebThread: Program received signal: "EXC_BAD_ACCESS"

Comment: I've encountered a number of problems with iOS 5, but so far they've been mostly due to some (undocumented and undescribed) changes in the way layout works.  Basic UITextFields (though not heavily used) have worked.  You might want to consider that perhaps some sort of layout messup is at the root of your problem.

Comment: BTW, quoting the assembler is pretty much useless.  Any error messages that might be in the console would be most helpful.

Comment: The console doesn't show any errors =(

Comment: Could as well be a zombie object (object released too often) at some other place in the code; I once encountered this type of error where on iOS 4.3 the zombie object would just be accepted silently (possibly creating a crash later) while on iOS 5.0 an immediate crash was encountered (although in some code not directly related).
Give instruments with the Zombie instrument a try and try to recreate the crash there.

Comment: Does everything else in your view initialize properly?

Comment: I just created a new class with XIB with a single UITextField in it not hooked up to anything and made that the root view controller of the window. Clicking the UITextField crashes the app.. So I guess it must be some setting in my project that is not compatible with iOS 5..?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Still not sure what the problem was but I was able to fix it by just copying all code across to a new project.

Comment: I don't think you "Fixed" the problem. If I were you I would add NSZombieEnabled to your current RunScheme (Product->Edit Scheme.. Select Run Scheme). Add NSZombieEnabled with value YES under "Enviroment Variables".

Comment: Honestly I don't think it's a memory issue in my code. It must have been some project setting that wasn't compatible with iOS 5 because with the new project I have no problems. I mean how could a totally empty view controller besides a single UITextField added in interface builder and not hooked up to anything have memory issues..

Comment: Still, my tip is a good tip. It will let you debug NSZombies (deallocated objects).

Answer (score 1):

This also happened for me and changing the product name fixed it. I had a ∂ character in my Product Name for my debug/dev version of the application which seemed to work fine on iOS 4.3 but not on iOS 5. It is an impossible correlation to figure out that tapping on a random UITextField (not all caused this for example if I changed the UITextField to secure it did not crash) would cause a crash because the Product Name contained a non-standard character.

I hope this helps someone else having this issue as I spent days trying to debug this.

Answer (score 0):

in my case it was the product name in the target settings which caused this strange error.