# UITextField crashes on touch

Tags: objective-c, ios, crash, uitextfield

Our ios application crashes when a `UITextField` with default type is touched.
There is another uitextfield which is numpad and it works okay.

The crash only occurs on ios 5.0.1 and ios 4.x works okay.

The `UITextField` is created with interface builder and I didn't add any delegates for it.

The project was created on 4.0.2 and I also tested the same project on 4.2.

If I create a new project and just put a `UITextField` in it there is no problem.

Somehow something in my project causes the `UITextField` to crash and I don't have any idea how to debug it.

The crash log is like following:

```
(gdb) bt
#0  0x33fa2fdc in CFRetain ()
#1  0x37991db6 in ___init_block_invoke_2 ()
#2  0x36c8e7ea in _dispatch_barrier_sync_f_invoke ()
#3  0x36c8e65a in dispatch_barrier_sync_f$VARIANT$up ()
#4  0x36c8e28e in dispatch_sync_f$VARIANT$up ()
#5  0x36c8e910 in dispatch_sync$VARIANT$up ()
#6  0x36c90576 in dispatch_once_f$VARIANT$up ()
#7  0x37992706 in CPLoggingAddCustomLogFile ()
#8  0x306ee658 in __MCLoggingInitialize_block_invoke_1 ()
#9  0x36c90576 in dispatch_once_f$VARIANT$up ()
#10 0x306ee6a4 in MCLoggingInitialize ()
#11 0x306ef060 in -[MCProfileConnection _init] ()
#12 0x306ef764 in +[MCProfileConnection sharedConnection] ()
#13 0x31758cce in _FTAreIDsEquivalent ()
#14 0x31758a46 in _FTAreIDsEquivalent ()
#15 0x317589c8 in _FTAreIDsEquivalent ()
#16 0x36c90576 in dispatch_once_f$VARIANT$up ()
#17 0x31758976 in _FTAreIDsEquivalent ()
#18 0x35026378 in GCC_except_table11 ()
#19 0x3504571c in _NSStringDescriptionForIMAVChatParticipantState ()
#20 0x350456a8 in _NSStringDescriptionForIMAVChatParticipantState ()
#21 0x36c90576 in dispatch_once_f$VARIANT$up ()
#22 0x35045656 in _NSStringDescriptionForIMAVChatParticipantState ()
#23 0x377931e2 in -[UIDictationController init] ()
#24 0x37793350 in +[UIDictationController sharedInstance] ()
#25 0x37793590 in +[UIDictationController fetchCurrentInputModeSupportsDictation] ()
#26 0x376b21d0 in -[UIKeyboardLayoutStar shouldShowDictationKey] ()
#27 0x374f4138 in -[UIKeyboardLayoutStar updateMoreAndInternationalKeys] ()
#28 0x374f206e in -[UIKeyboardLayoutStar setKeyplaneName:] ()
#29 0x374f0e62 in -[UIKeyboardLayoutStar showKeyboardType:appearance:orientation:withShift:] ()
#30 0x37481bc4 in -[UIKeyboardImpl updateLayout] ()
#31 0x37425f6a in -[UIKeyboardImpl setDelegate:force:] ()
#32 0x37407f22 in -[UIPeripheralHost(UIKitInternal) _reloadInputViewsForResponder:] ()
#33 0x37407c6e in -[UIResponder(UIResponderInputViewAdditions) reloadInputViews] ()
#34 0x374077aa in -[UIResponder becomeFirstResponder] ()
#35 0x37505d76 in -[UITextInteractionAssistant setFirstResponderIfNecessary] ()
#36 0x37505640 in -[UITextInteractionAssistant oneFingerTap:] ()
#37 0x37504f06 in _UIGestureRecognizerSendActions ()
#38 0x37496c1c in -[UIGestureRecognizer _updateGestureWithEvent:] ()
#39 0x376c2508 in ___UIGestureRecognizerUpdate_block_invoke_0541 ()
#40 0x37411d68 in _UIGestureRecognizerApplyBlocksToArray ()
#41 0x374108b6 in _UIGestureRecognizerUpdate ()
#42 0x3741d3cc in _UIGestureRecognizerUpdateGesturesFromSendEvent ()
#43 0x3741d20e in -[UIWindow _sendGesturesForEvent:] ()
#44 0x3741cddc in -[UIWindow sendEvent:] ()
#45 0x374034ec in -[UIApplication sendEvent:] ()
#46 0x37402d2c in _UIApplicationHandleEvent ()
#47 0x30835df2 in PurpleEventCallback ()
#48 0x3402e552 in __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE1_PERFORM_FUNCTION__ ()
#49 0x3402e4f4 in __CFRunLoopDoSource1 ()
#50 0x3402d342 in __CFRunLoopRun ()
#51 0x33fb04dc in CFRunLoopRunSpecific ()
#52 0x33fb03a4 in CFRunLoopRunInMode ()
#53 0x30834fcc in GSEventRunModal ()
#54 0x37431742 in UIApplicationMain ()
#55 0x00002462 in main (argc=1, argv=0x2fdffb04) at /Users/xxxx/Desktop/ios5/
```

Comment: What kind of exception or error is it?

Comment: a little more would be nice, how are you creating the field, maybe some code for the delegate methods, especially anything that has some blocking GCD code...

Comment: Are you doing anything ARC specific on touch or on any other related delegate methods?

Comment: @PhilippeSabourin it doesnt give any error it just exits on the line: "int retVal = UIApplicationMain(argc, argv, nil, @"xyzAppDelegate");"

Comment: Oh, you need to add the breakpoint exception...  To do this with Xcode 4, click on the Breakpoints symbol (2nd from the right) in the Navigator pane, click the + button at the bottom of the pane, and select Add Exception Breakpoint. THen on the right of the exception line you'll see the error/exception.

Comment: @GradyPlayer I didnt write any delegate functions

Comment: @PhilippeSabourin i added the exception breakpoint and it still stops at the line: "int retVal = UIApplicationMain(argc, argv, nil, @"xyzAppDelegate");"

Comment: And it doesn't say anything on the right side of the green highlighted line?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Change "Product Name"

I had exactly same problem. I've solved it with changing **"Product Name"** property on build settings of target. Looks like having **Non-USA characters**, special characters like "*ü, ğ, ç*" etc. masses up your application.

I've absolutely no idea why this creates a problem such. But making product name something like "Ocu" instead of "Öcü" fixes it.

I found about this information on another question's answer and [here is the link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9163651/656473).

Answer (score 0):

Make sure in interface builder that the UITextField does not have any current outlets. It's a common mishap to duplicate existing UITextFields and not realize that they were previously linked to other outlets or making references to things that are no longer there.

Comment: The problem exists even if i create a new uitextfield on the same project by interface builder or with code.