# iPhone - Changing product name to non USA characters causes crash

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode, cocoa

My application used to work just fine. When I changed the Product name to non-USA characters 2 very strange problems appeared:

1. When I touch a UITextField the application crashes.
2. The application cannot play sound that is saved to disk.

The issue (1) has been mentioned before but I cannot understand why it happens and how to solve it. Check out last comment: [UITextField causes crash in iOS 5, works fine in iOS 4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8145491/uitextfield-causes-crash-in-ios-5-works-fine-in-ios-4/9163651#9163651)

If I go back to English everything will be fine. But I need an application name with non USA characters.

Comment: That definitely sounds like a bug. Report to Apple?

Comment: Once the app name is changed, have you manually edited the app ID (the “com.companyname.appname” string) to be sure it only contains ASCII characters?

Answer (score 1):

I don't know where you have changed Your product name. As per my knowledge you have to change  the value of key 'Bundle name' in '<>-Info.plist' file.

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't find any specific rules about the character set allowed in the Product Name, but I would keep it in ASCII just to be safe, and perform any customizations to the name using Bundle Display Name (and/or Bundle Name) in your Info.plist file. This would let you have a different application name for different user languages (I'm assuming you want localized app name(s)).

As to what is actually causing your app to crash, it could be that bundle paths are mangled because you have non-ASCII characters in the product name, but I don't have proof of that. Try the suggestion above and see if it works for you.